# GWT compile button in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, shortcut, gwt-compiler

A simple question :

I am using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo and have updated the GWT (2.4) Eclipse plugin.

Now I can't find the **GWT compile button** in the main toolbar.

Previously there was this symbol in the main toolbar [image: GWT Compile Button],
but after the update, this button has disappeared and the compile action has been moved as a submenu  entry into the "Google Services and Development Tools", represented in the main toolbar by this symbol [image].

Is there a way to add the **GWT compile button** to the main toolbar or to specify a shortcut?

It's really exhausting to click on the "Google Services and Development Tools" to reach the compile submenu entry :-)

Comment: No good answer? What crap is this, I thought GWT was "mature" by now? We still have to put up with this nonsense? This isn't rocket science Google! It's actually worse than described above, because you have to first click the project folder in the package explorer.

Answer (score 4):

Highlight your project
right-click on it
go down in the dropdown menu to "Google"
The submenu of "Google" will have the "GWT Compile" button

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Juno, GWT Compile option is located on the toolbar underneath the Google logo as seen here:

[image]

There is no key binding in Eclipse Juno for GWT Compile. That seems to be something the plugin could provide, but does not.

Comment: Is anyone actually using this tool? This kind of unpolished stuff is the kind of annoying thing that should be quickly stomped out, if only to preserve Google staff's sanity...

Comment: @Perce: I sometimes feel that way about GWT

Comment: It's a shame because if we're not going to give up on the never-ending "standards" battle in favor of a simple virtual-machine-based solution like Flex (Flash), Silverlight, Java, etc, the next best thing is something like GWT. JavaScript, CSS, and DOM are just miserable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button for any command to the toolbar by go to `Window -> Customize Perspective` and exploring the dialog there. You may need to enable things using the Command and Menu visibility and then in the first tab you can add the buttons to the toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't find it in Customize Perspective so far. What do you think i may need to enable?  "You may need to enable things using the Command and Menu visibility and then in the first tab you can add the buttons to the toolbar."

Comment: If it's not anywhere in the 2nd or 2rd tabs, then I think you are out of luck, they don't have a specific command for it. However also look through preferences and see if you can find anything related to compiling. Maybe there is something there. Do you find a menu item for launching the compile?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems to me that there is no such entry. The only thing i found is, to show/hide the "Google Services and Development Tools" button in the toolbar, but the subitems like "GWT compile project" are not available

Comment: @sockeqwe yeah exactly, I can't find such entry too, only "Google Services and Development Tools". It's a shame that there is currently no quick and convenient way to compile gwt project :(.

Comment: Have you tried "right button" on the toolbar? You should also see the "Customize Perspective" option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to add the toolbar item back, but you can run the compiler via keyboard shortcut:

- Debug Compile GWT Application, **Alt+Shift+D, C**
- Run Compile GWT Application, **Alt+Shift+X, C**

You can also customize the keyboard shortcut if you wish, by going to Window->Preferences->Keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile a GWT application, you should install the Google plugin. Here are [the links.](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download)